# Use of undeclared identifier in Objective-C, trying to set up ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to set up a scrollView for my content in my app, but even though I declare the scroller in the .h code, when I try to use it in the the .m file I get a 'use of undeclared identifier' error.

This is the code in my .h file:

```
  @interface ViewController :UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
  }
```

And this is the code in my .m file:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];     //error here
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)]; //and error here
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So, in your `.m` file, is there really a `@implementation ViewController`?

Comment: And have you done `#import "ViewController.h"`?

Comment: it was as simple as the import ... sorry I'm so new to this but massively appreciate your help!